# How to prove these triangles are similar?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

I have the following setup.

[image: Click for diagram]

A triangle $ABC$ has incentre $I$ and $AB>AC$. $E$ is a point on the circumcircle of $ABC$ such that $\angle IEA=90^\circ$. $U$ is a point on $AC$ such that $IU$ is perpendicular to $AC$, and $W$ is a point on $AB$ such that $IW$ is perpendicular to $AB$.

How do I prove that $\triangle EUC$ is similar to $\triangle EWB$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly we have for triangles $EUC$ and $EWB$,
$$\angle ECU = \angle EBW$$
subtended by chord $AE$ on the circumcircle $(ABC)$.

Also $E,U,W$ lie on the circle with diameter $AI$. So
$$\angle AUE= \angle AWE$$
$$\Rightarrow \angle EUC= \angle EWB$$

Thus $\triangle EUC \sim \triangle EWB$ by angle-angle similarity criterion.

Comment: Thank you, I follow the last lines, however could you please explain how $\angle ECU=\angle EBW$? I think I may be unaware of a theorem used here.

Comment: @KN7811 $\angle ECU = \angle ECA = \angle EBA = \angle EBW$.

Comment: Oh of course. Thank you so much!